# Obtaining Client UID for login

Tags: php, authentication, authorization, uid

I have seen a few questions/answers in regards to this, but none really suit or answer the issue I have. Feel free to mark as duplicate if I have managed to miss anything.

I am currently writing a web application in PHP that requires a user to log in before they can access, BUT we need the application to only let a user log in from their authorized PC. For example, when a user first logs in, they will get a prompt to alert the admin to auth their PC, once done so they can continue. I have been searching the net for ways to obtain a UID from the device hardware but understand that PHP is server side, not client side, so all the values that have been returned, have been related to the server and not the client (i.e HDD Serial).

I'm a little stuck for the best way to achieve this, I have considered the below so far:

- IP Addresses: Customer does not use a static IP, and we have seen that the IP they are using is constantly changing for each PC.
- MAC Address: Cannot for the life in me find anything that would help me write something to grab the MAC, or whether its possible?
- exec(): Had a play with this, but again, appears to return server values.
- Javascript: My knowledge of Javascript isn't advanced enough yet to even consider trying to write something for this.

I'm a little stuck other than that (Junior Developer) so any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will not be able to get client info with server-side language. All you can do is retrieve things like user's browser, os version and other things that can be easily faked. If you don't have to use a hardware uid, consider using simple sessions instead.

Comment: Hi @Marius, That's what I thought in all honesty, but was hoping someone would have a workaround as such. If i use sessions, will it be cleared if the user clears their browser history and all that stuff? Not entirely sure how they work. We are trying to avoid the admins having to re-auth users time and time again...

Comment: Sessions are cleared as soon as you delete cookies or they expire. If you really must have some sort of "permanent" solution, you could make the clients use chrome browser and install something like "modify headers" extension. With it you could enable chrome browser to send you additional authentification headers that you could access in php's $_SERVER array. For instance, your admins could set a header "LC-AUTH": "somerandomtext". That way you could check for the presence of $_SERVER['HTTP_LC_AUTH'] header and see if it matches "somerandomtext". That's just one of many "workarounds".

Comment: Right, i'll have a word with my Boss and suggest this one, see if we can make it work.. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: You're welcome. A more simple solution though would be to make your clients login to your system with a unique url instead of just example.com. Just use something like example.com/login/somerandomstring (just bookmark it this way). That could automatically create a cookie with this additional authentication info if the cookie does not exist yet or was deleted. And then just redirect the user to the actual system. Note: you still should use passwords for users on top of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else wants to achieve this, I resolved this issue by creating a database table for "authorised_computers" which stores a value generated during the log in process within a COOKIE. This code is passed onto an administrator who can either authorise, or de-authorise the machine allowing them to login. Once the admin has authorised, when the user tries to login, the login script will check the database and cookie values to ensure they match. Only downside is, if the user clears their cookies, they will have to re-authorise. But with how simple it is for admins to actually authorise, it shouldn't be too much of a headache.